# Optaplanner : dynamic termination config

Tags: optaplanner

I want to configure my termination strategy dynamically. My intention is that the solver should terminate when either it has tried 10k steps or when the score has not improved for 4k steps. For that I am setting the phases in config as follows:

```
<constructionHeuristic></constructionHeuristic>
<localSearch></localSearch>
```

And then before starting the solver, I set

```
TerminationConfig terminationConfig = new TerminationConfig();
terminationConfig.setTerminationCompositionStyle(TerminationCompositionStyle.OR);
terminationConfig.setUnimprovedStepCountLimit(4000);
terminationConfig.setStepCountLimit(10000);

LocalSearchPhaseConfig localSearchPhaseConfig = (LocalSearchPhaseConfig) solverFactory.getSolverConfig().getPhaseConfigList().get(1);
localSearchPhaseConfig.setTerminationConfig(terminationConfig);
```

I tried keeping the value of `unimprovedStepCount` as 1 but it still does not terminate after 30-40 minutes. How can I define this config?

Also, do I need to define the `constructionHeuristic` and `constructionHeuristic` in the xml config explicitly or are they inferred by default?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it this ?

```
  <localSearch>
    <termination>
      <terminationCompositionStyle>OR</terminationCompositionStyle>
      <unimprovedStepCountLimit>4000</unimprovedStepCountLimit>
      <stepCountLimit>10000</stepCountLimit>
    </termination>
  </localSearch>
```

If you don't define a CH the default is `FIRST_FIT` I believe.

Comment: I want to keep the configuration dynamic so that I can receive it as a request parameter and configure it. Hence I was trying to set it when I create the solver instance. Any way to do that?

`If you don't define a CH the default is FIRST_FIT I believe`
I did not get this. Should I define the `FIRST_FIT` in my Construction Heuristics?

Comment: First prove that it works with this XML approach. Anything possible there is possible in the API too. Turn on debug logging and check if any of the steps indeed have a step that doesn't have "new" best score.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my `SelectionFilter`. There was a bug such that the `accept` method of `SelectionFilter` was always returning false and hence the local search phase was not progressing at all.

After resolving it, the dynamic termination config works as it is.